# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception gradle

Tags: android, json, gradle

I'm facing this problem for a long time and I did not find any solution so I hope to find it Here.

What I did to solve this problem:

- Try to delete all ads and there codes and rebuild again.
- When I delete `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`  it runs  without any problem.

> > Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
>   > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.     Searched Location:
>   >     C:\Users\Mrwan\Desktop\QassWaNwadar\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
>   >     C:\Users\Mrwan\Desktop\QassWaNwadar\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
>   >     C:\Users\Mrwan\Desktop\QassWaNwadar\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
>   >     C:\Users\Mrwan\Desktop\QassWaNwadar\app\src\debug\google-services.json
>   >     C:\Users\Mrwan\Desktop\QassWaNwadar\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
>   >     C:\Users\Mrwan\Desktop\QassWaNwadar\app\google-services.json
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 6s

Gradle Module app

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.date.brian.cradletest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: But did you include the google-services.json? If not, then you need to add it. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purpose of `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` is to add dependencies for basic libraries required for the services you have enabled.

Since you have already included `implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'` you don't actually need it. Removing `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` should work as your expected.

If you want to continue using `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` then, as the error says:

> File google-services.json is missing.

You are `missing google-services.json` file which is generally placed in the app/ directory (at the root of the Android Studio app module). You can follow this [official document](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file) to add this file correctly.

**Note:**
Also ensure that all your support libraries share same version.

Comment: you mean i can use one of these apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  OR implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'  ????

Comment: googel-services.josn i added to app file in first time but now i removing now add the file again same error !

Comment: Based on Official document you should only use specific library so that your final apk size is optimum. So you should only add `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1`

Comment: You need to clean and Rebuild after you add the .json file.

Comment: i did it clean and Rebuild ... nothing

Comment: It doesnt work after you remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`?

Comment: its ok thak you for help :)